# Prove that the following algorithm has STOP property (number of steps is finite)

Tags: algorithms, algorithm-analysis, correctness-proof

Prove that the following algorithm has STOP property. I am not sure if this term is widely know, so the definition of STOP property that I got during classes looks as follows:

> STOP property (for all input data satisfying $ \alpha $ the computation halts - the number of steps is finite)

$\alpha: x \in N $

```
void BB(int x)
{
    int y = x;
    int z = 0;
    while((z != 0) || (y <= 300))
    {
        if(y <= 300)
        {
            y = y + 3;
            z = z + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            y = y - 2;
            z = z - 1;
        }
    }
}
```

I do not really have any idea how to approach such a problem. I was thinking about using the method of loop counters, but I couldn't success with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have three possible cases:

- $y > 300$. Since $z = 0$ initially, the algorithm terminates.
- $y = 300$ and $z = 0$.
  You enter the first if and you get $y = 303$ and $z = 1$. Then you enter the second if and you get $y = 301$ and $z = 0$. Since $y > 300$ and $z = 0$  the algorithm stops.
- $y < 300$ and $z = 0$.
  After $k$ iterations $y = 301$ or $y = 302$ or $y=303$ and $z = k$. By executing the algorithm for each $y$ you can see that $y$ only takes values in a specific range while $z$ is always decreasing and will eventually reach 0 (or it will become less than 0). For example, let $y = 301$ and $z = k$. By executing the algorithm you get the following values:

  ${\bf y = 301, z = k} \\
  y = 299, z=k-1 \\
  y=302, z = k\\
  y = 300, z = k-1 \\
  y = 303, z = k \\
  {\bf y = 301, z = k-1}\\
  y = 299, z = k-2 \\
  y=302, z = k-1\\
  y = 300, z = k-2 \\
  y = 303, z = k-1 \\
  {\bf y = 301, z = k-2}\\$

  Obviously each time you reach $y = 301$, z is decreased by 1. After showing that the same thing happens for the other two possible values of $y$ you have proved that for every possible starting value, the algorithm stops after a finite number of steps.

Answer (score 2):

A simple case: What happens if x > 300? (Think about it). So that was easy, the program stops.

What if x ≤ 300, including x = 0? First there is  a phase where y is increased by 3 each time, and that will happen at least once (if x ≥ 298) and at most 101 times (if x = 0), so we end that phase with x ≤ 101, and y is 301, 302, or 303.

Now comes a second phase: We have y = 301, 302, or 303. If y = 301 (you think what the next two steps will be), and we have y = 302 and x unchanged. If y = 302 (you think what the next two steps will be), and we have y = 303 and x unchanged. But in the last case y = 303 (you think what the next three steps will be), and we have y = 301 and x is one less than before!

If x isn't 0 already, you figure out what will happen after every 7 iterations of the loop, and then it is obvious that the program stops.